# Straight line equation

Tags: logical-deduction

We have the following reasoning.

> A < B < C < A

Can you make this statement solvable?
Find
-2 solutions by removing 2 straight lines and adding 2 straight lines.
-1 solution by adding 3 straight lines.
-1 solution by adding only 1 straight line.

NOTE
The solutions must be aesthetically acceptable.
The solutions must be simple. No fancy symbols accepted.

Comment: That appears to be an inequality, not an equation. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2 solutions by removing 2 straight lines and adding 2 straight lines.

> $A\lt B\lt C+A, A\lt B\lt C\gt A$

1 solution by adding 3 straight lines.

> $A\le B\le C\le A$

1 solution by adding only 1 straight line.

> going with JA on this, $-A\lt B\lt C\lt A$

Comment: I'll give you this one because you are the first one to give me 2 original solutions for the remove 2 add 2 part. Although what I had in mind was to change 1 A to "F" or "Z", in the end there was much more solutions that expected.(I had a feeling it would end up like that but I thought people would have fun trying to solve this puzzle so I made it anyway)

Comment: A<B<C+A doesn't work always. Consider A=-100, B= 0, C=1.

Comment: @CodeNewbie 'Make the equation solvable' -> it's still solvable e.g. A, B, C = 1, 2, 3

Comment: Alternatively, for the adding one line, you can do a crossed out not less than

Answer (score 8):

Seems like there may be a huge number of ways to achieve these, but here are some...

Removing 2 straight lines and adding 2 straight lines in two ways:

> $H<B<C<A$
>  and
>  $A<B<C<H$

Adding 3 straight lines:

> $L-A<B<C<A$

Adding 1 straight line:

> $-A<B<C<A$

Comment: The solution for 1 line is the one I had in mind. The solution with 3 lines is quite clever, I like it, mine was much simpler. and the 2 solutions for 2 lines I would consider them to be just 1, although that would be quite questionable.

Answer (score 7):

2 solutions by removing 2 straight lines and adding 2 straight lines.

> `A > B < C < A`
>  `A < B < C > A`
>  In both cases two straight lines removed are `<`, two straight lines added: `>`

1 solution by adding 3 straight lines.

> `A ≤ B ≤ C ≤ A`
>  which resolves to `A = B = C = A`.
>  Three lines added are 'or-equal' lines in `≤` symbol made of `<`.

1 solution by adding only 1 straight line.

> –A < B < C < A
>   A line added is the minus sign.

Comment: +1 That is the solution I had in mind for the 3 lines, good job!

Answer (score 5):

What do you think about this solution? It holds true without changing anything :)

> rock < paper < scissors < rock

Comment: Joined the community just to upvote this answer. In a similar vein, any set of objects works if we define a [non-transitive $<$ order relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) on them. Many such examples exist, for instance numbers in a [modulus ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks :) Rock, paper, scissors was just one example and it was more meant as a bonus answer since it technically doesn't fulfill the requirements of adding and removing lines.

Answer (score 4):

For the third question:

> $A < B < C \nless A$

Of course this suggests two other possible solutions:

> $A < B \nless C < A$

and

> $A \nless B < C < A$

I don't think this counts as using "fancy symbols."

Answer (score 4):

Some *logical* answers

2 solutions by removing 2 straight lines and adding 2 straight lines.

> $A\lt B\lor C\lt A$, logical or
>  $A\lt B \land C\lt A$, logical and

1 solution by adding 3 straight lines.

> $A\lt B\leftrightarrow C\lt A$, if and only if

1 solution by adding only 1 straight line.

> $A\lt B\leftarrow C\lt A$, less common way of doing implication, latter implies former

Comment: Nice. Do note, however, that these imply that the original is already "solvable" (evaluating to false) and that one of the first two* will evaluate to false. * Which one depending upon operator precedence, unless we define a rather strange intermingled ordering of precedence between logical and comparison operators.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I would treat logical operations as the lowest precedence, so it is like (A<B)∨(C<A). All of my solutions can be evaluated as true which was my goal instead of just solvable, note 'or' is not 'xor'.

Comment: Ah yes, true, they can both evaluate as true, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions by removing 2 straight lines and adding 2 straight lines <sub>(slightly different from Jonathan’s)</sub>:

> A < B < C < VI
> or
> A < B < C < XI
> (You can also do IV and IX, but the spacing is tight.)

1 solution by adding 3 straight lines <sub>(slightly different from Jonathan’s)</sub>:

> 4A < B < C < A
> (can be solved with A = −1, B = −3, and C = −2)

1 solution by adding only 1 straight line.

> $A < B < \overline{C < A}$
>
> The [overline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline) is a [vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)), which groups a subexpression. 
> So the above is equivalent to:
>
> $A < B < (C < A)$
>
> Using the standard (?) paradigm of TRUE ≡ 1 and FALSE ≡ 0,
> this can be solved with any A < B < 0 and C ≥ A,  or  C < A < B < 1.
>
> Note that $\overline{A < B} < C < A$ would also work.

Comment: P.S.   Yes, I also figured out the other three-line answer and the other one-line answers before I read the other posts.